# blocking apache directories from mod_authz_owner writes

Tags: apache

I've got a customer whose site is getting hacked. An id file keeps getting changed and the hacker authenticates the site as his own.

I tried changing file permissions so apache can't overwrite the correct file, but the hosting company is running apache as the site owner. I'm assuming that's part of the mod_authz_owner module.

Is there anyway to block apache from writing to certain directories under docroot? There's a general upload area that needs to be written to, but the rest of the site that contains code should only allow sftp to write to it.

It's a cloud site running virtual hosting and a freebsd linux version. Apache 2 something, i don't have command line access to query it.
Thanks.
-Don-

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question, there is no 100% way to do it if your scripts are running as the files owner. The owner can do anything with it's files, logically.

You can set read-only (0444) permissions for these files, but the malware can set other permissions the same way.

You can try to set an immutable attribute using [chflags](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chflags&sektion=1) (on BSD) or [chattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) (on Linux). But the malware can set it off also.

The right way is to determine and fight the vulnerability, not it's consequences.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't run across chattr before.